# Error while sending QUERY packet after a while

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, chat

I'm working on a chat application using WebSocket. However, after 1 day of starting the WebSocket Listener, I cannot execute any SQL query. I get the error below.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

I have tried to change max_allowed_packet to 16M and wait_timeout is quite high but they didn't fix the problem. Here is some of my codes.

```
function getToken( $user_id )
{
    $query = db_query("SELECT `token` FROM `members` WHERE `ID` = '$user_id' LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query );
    return $row['token'];
}
...
while(@socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 16777216, 0) >= 1) 
{           
    $received_text = unmask($buf); // Unmask Data
    $chat_msg = json_decode($received_text); // Decode JSON Data
    if(isset($chat_msg))
    { 
         ... Variables ...

         if($token === getToken($user_id))
         { ... }
    }
}
...
```

MySQL gives the error on `if($token === getToken($user_id))` this code. `getToken` function cannot get the token from database after a while.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `db_query`?

Comment: [db_query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2m60107m23nuue/Screenshot%20%28145%29.png?dl=0)

Comment: If this is a long-running application, you probably need to close and reopen the connection periodically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks it's working.